# Can TransactionScope rollback be used with Selenium or Watin?

Tags: c#, asp.net, selenium, xunit.net

I am trying to do some automated web testing of my ASP.NET application.  I was hoping to use the AutoRollback attribute from Xunit.net extensions to undo any database changes that were made during the test.  AutoRollback uses TransactionScope to start a transaction before the test and roll it back afterwards.

When I try to hit my web application during a transaction, it always times out.  It seems like this should work, any ideas?  Here is my test:

```
[Fact]
[AutoRollback]
public void Entity_should_be_in_list()
{
    Entity e = new Entity
    {
        Name = "Test",
    };
    dataContext.Entities.InsertOnSubmit(e);
    dataContext.SubmitChanges();

    selenium.Open("http://localhost/MyApp");
    Assert.True(selenium.IsTextPresent("Test"));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your ASP.NET application has a separate database context and it has no idea that you want it to join transaction started by Xunit.net. Apparently, the database locks some resources when transaction starts; web application waits patiently for some time and eventually gives up.

I think your best bet is to start from empty database and use SQL script to create schema and populate lookup tables (your database is [under source control](https://blog.codinghorror.com/get-your-database-under-version-control/), right?). Another approach is to backup database before running the tests and then restore it once they finish.

Comment: You know, that seems so obvious now that you said it :)  I was hoping to avoid building up and tearing down the database all the time, but I guess I'm stuck with it.

Comment: You need to find a way to enable transaction support in LINQ to SQL so that it can join into the existing transaction scope.